# migrating AD users on XP and Win 7 clients from child to parent domain over VPN

Tags: active-directory, vpn, migration

we are looking to migrate 35k users around the globe from 60+ child domains into the parent (root) domain. We are able to migrate the users using ADMT. The users can afterwards logon with their root domain credentials and everything works fine. 
However, we have a good number of users that only connect through VPN. We are using a user certificate based VPN. The user has to first logon to the workstation using his cached credentials from the legacy domain, then he can establish a secure connection to the corporate network (authenticated through the user cert against the VPN end point).
We are able to migrate the users into the parent domain. As long as the client does not have connectivity to a DC, the user is able to logon with his cached credentials and even start the VPN connection. At this point he would have to log off and then log on with his new (root) domain credentials. However, as soon as he logs off the VPN tunnel gets terminated and the user is unable to authenticate against the DC of the root domain. Without that first authentication there are no cached credentials of the root domain that can be stored on the client and we are back to the beginning. Unfortunately, the VPN client cannot be configured in a way that would allow the user to log off and keep the VPN tunnel established. We also tried to do a "runas" or a "Switch user" but it would not work.

Any suggestions? I hope I was clear, if not let me know and I'll be happy to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

I've been through a similar situation.  We had three decent solutions:

1. In remote offices where everyone connects over VPN, send them a
   site-to-site VPN device to connect through.
2. Have the users send their laptop to a regional center that does have full corporate connectivity for migration.
3. Cross-ship hard drives that have been imaged for their model of computer.

We ended up using all three solutions, depending on the local staff.  Since the machine SID changes, you can't depend on a VPN solution that uses certificates to connect prior to logon since the private key will be lost after the SID changes.

I tried blueprinting an elaborate PPTP VPN based solution with local user accounts, but you would not be able to script some parts, and I was overall uncomfortable with the many places it could fail/break.